# Hide the Surrogate key in LookUpEdit

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I am using the [LookUpEdit](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsLookUpEdittopic) control. I bound two columns, a primary key (GUID) and a human readable string. I only want people to see the human readable string, but I want to preserve the relationship between the string value and it's primary key value.

I can't seem to hide the primary key from displaying on dropdown. I've tried the DevExpress forum and their [proposed solution](http://community.devexpress.com/forums/p/58999/278308.aspx) does not work for me. So I tried hooking into the `ListChanged` event. That is not working either.

```
private void DataBind()
{
    messageTypeCbB.ListChanged += new ListChangedEventHandler(messageTypeCbB_ListChanged);
    messageTypeCbB.Properties.DataSource = viewModel.SomeNoteTypes.ToArray();
    //another attempt at hiding the columns.  This fails too.  
    //messageTypeCbB.Properties.ForceInitialize();
    //messageTypeCbB.Properties.PopulateColumns();
    //messageTypeCbB.Properties.Columns[0].Visible = false;
    messageTypeCbB.Properties.DisplayMember = "NodeType";
    messageTypeCbB.Properties.ValueMember = "SomeNoteType_ID";

    fromTxt.Text = viewModel.From;
    dateTimeDd.DateTime = viewModel.Date;
}

void messageTypeCbB_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
{            
    //For whatever reason this won't hide the column
    (sender as DevExpress.XtraEditors.LookUpEdit).Properties.Columns[0].Visible = false;
}
```

How can I hide the surrogate key?  (Hide ValueMember display only DisplayMember)

DevExpress v11.1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was calling `DataBind()` from my Form constructor.  I moved the call into the `Form Load` event and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the *other* method suggested in that forum listing? i.e. not setting `Visible` to false but rather explicitly adding the columns you want to be displayed to the `Columns` collection.  Try `Columns.Clear()` then add your column(s).  Or try `PopulateColumns()` then `Columns.RemoveAt(0);`

Comment: I want to preserve the relationship between the string value and it's primary key value.